# Android error: What is wrong with this code?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

In the onclick method of onItemclicklistener, I am trying to get the id of the item which has been selected. I think it is wrong. What is the correct way to do it? I want to later link this to another activity which will play the selected song. Will using explicit intent be the best method to do it?

```
public class SongListFragment extends Fragment {

private int audioIndex;
public SongListFragment() { }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
    ListView audioView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.song_view);
    final ArrayList<String> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    final Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().
                            getContentResolver().
                            query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
            } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                android.R.id.text1, audioList);
    audioView.setAdapter(adapter);
    audioView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
            final Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().
                    getContentResolver().
                    query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

            if (audioCursor != null) {
                if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());}}
            audioCursor.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.select+audioCursor.getString(audioIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;

}
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve, PID: 5832
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2082 requested, with a size of 2082
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve.SongListFragment$1.onItemClick(SongListFragment.java:72)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
11-19 17:05:08.108 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
11-19 17:05:09.742 5832-5832/com.bignerdranch.android.songretrieve I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5832 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting please.

Comment: you are not using position variable of onItemClick anywhere in your itemClick. Check your code once. with the help of this position variable you will be able to retrieve value of selected row

Comment: @vguzzi my phone got disconnected before I could see the error. But the apk i installed on my phone didn't run. Initially, except the onItemClick part, everything was running fine. The songs were getting retrieved.

Comment: @Anjali, just saying, that even if it is the wrong way, the rest of the code should work right? I mean, that code will be called up only when a listitem will be clicked. Until then, the songs should be retrieved in a list, shouldnt they?

Comment: @SidharthKriplani It would be a lot easier to find you a solution if you reproduced the error and pasted your logcat.

Comment: @vguzzi been trying that. Will get back as soon as it is done.

Comment: @vguzzi, pasted the logcat. And the list is getting retrieved now except that the app crashes when i click on an item.

Comment: yes rest of the code is fine only thing you missed is to retrieve the content of specific position

Comment: @Anjali, any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line:

```
int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)-1;
```

It seems that you are getting an out of bounds exception thrown because it is starting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: this didnt work. I am thinking there  must be something to do with the position?

Answer (score 0):

Your onItem click listener should be like this:

```
audioView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           int clickedAudioIndex = Integer.parseInt(audioList.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.select+audioCursor.getString(clickedAudioIndex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    });
```